# Controllers naming convention in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

All controllers in Laravel 5 are still named with `Controller` suffix, like `AuthController` and `PasswordController`. Is there any reason to follow this convention with own controllers, or are those suffixes just leftovers from pre-namespacing era?

I use action-based URL generation most of the time, so I avoid linking like `url('home')`, but prefer something like `action('HomeController@index)` instead. This way I can change URL patterns without a headache.

But `action('Home@index')` is so much more elegant. Any traps behind it?

Comment: “This way I can change URL patterns without a headache.” You can’t change controller class names without a headache now, and I tend to re-factor controllers a lot more than my URLs.

Comment: @MartinBean I don't understand what you mean. I'm not refactoring anything, I was talking about being able to change URL any time later during development, so if I decide to - let's say - change `/login` to `/sign-in`. When I use actions as a base, it's super easy. It would be even more flexible with naming routes, but I don't like to have named routes.

Comment: Your URLs shouldn’t change. Why break caches, search results, and users’ bookmarks? Your code may change though, and code changes some times include re-naming classes. Therefore, if you’re using action-based links and you change a controller’s name, you’re going to have to update _every_ link that pointed to that controller.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to add the Controller suffix. If it was really needed, when you create a Controller through artisan, it would automatically add it, or complain about it, and it is not. So, feel free (but keep in mind that if you want a controller "Dog" and there is a model "Dog"... well, it will be complicated).

Comment: How is it complicated when I have Dog model and Dog controller? :) They would sit in different namespaces, so not a big deal.

Comment: Of course, if you want, you can name all your files with the same name, just change the directory and namespace. I'm not saying it's impossible, but you're using your prefered text editor with multiple files open, it's hard to tell which one is the file with the Model and wich one is the one with the Controller. Or the service. Or the css. You don't even need to name your style files with .css, you know. Just call it Password.php. Hey, it can be fun!

Comment: I use Sublime Text and I just hit `cmd+p` and type `controllerdog` (or shorter) and I will know it's a controller, because they are in `Http/Controller` folder. I don't think it makes much of a difference during your workflow.

Comment: I think the main reason it's complicated is that the `Dog` controller will usually require the `Dog` model, so if you import the `Dog` model with `use`, you'll have to alias it: `namespace Controllers; use Models\Dog as DogModel; class Dog extends Controller {}` kinda thing. But yes, you can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Then maybe it's a good idea to add "Controller" as suffix and not as prefix: When you write "dog" you'll get both dogController.php and Dog.php. Anyway, no trick behind, but keep in mind why conventions are useful.

Comment: But I'm not adding any prefixes. The controller file is Dog.php and the class is `App\Http\Controllers\Dog`. This is how Sublime Text searches files - you can type just a part of full path. I can even type just `condog` and there's huge chance it will match this only Dog controller file.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Controller` at the end of every controller class name does feel like a type of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). However, a class's name should tell the programmer quickly and unambiguously what it does. A `DogController` is not a `Dog`. In fact, I can't think of a better name than `DogController` for it.

Yes, it is namespaced as `App\Http\Controllers\DogController` which seems like double handling, but how often do you think about or refer to a class by its fully qualified name? Most often a class is referred to just by its class name, and PHP even allows you to do this in code with `use App\Http\Controllers\DogController;` which will make `DogController` a valid class name in your code.

That being said, Laravel will not force you to use this convention. If you are working with other programmers you need to have an agreed naming convention, and using Laravel's is the easiest as well as the one most Laravel programmers will already be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

No need of adding Controller Suffix. It is just user recognition. So that we can easily get that is an controller. You can normally create Home instead of HomeController. And `action('Home@index')` will perfectly work. But models in Laravel is something different. If your model name is in singular your table name will be plural. And this is also not a compulsory thing. But if we add Controller in suffix it would be best in using controller and model. Because we will add `use home` and `use app\home` in the controller. This would confuse us.

Comment: I still think that having model and controller with the same name is not a reason to keep the suffix. This is not what namespacing philosophy is. In those cases, I use something like `use App\Http\Controllers\Dog as DogController` - this way you just pollute import section with the suffix, not the entire class.

Comment: I said that too. I said that would confuse if we has the same name for our controller and model.